# Error while installing ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows10 using wubi

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wubi, filesystem

I am using windows10 in my system. 
I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 10 using wubi. 
It shows the following error. If I click "ok", then it shows the same error again. [image]

Comment: I also have never installed Ubuntu with Wubi (as I don't dual boot), however I have found no indication that it is compatible with any Windows version newer than Windows 7. I think it generally won;t work with UEFI firmware.

Comment: @Bruni My system has UEFI boot system. But i turned of it and using legacy boot only.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi does not support new machines with Windows 8 and Windows 10. So get an ISO and make a live DVD/USB and install from it.

From [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide):

> Wubi is an officially supported installer for Windows XP, Vista and 7
>   only. Wubi does not work with Windows 8 default boot-loader.
>   Thus at this point Wubi would not work on a new Windows 8 machine. You
>   would be able to install, but not reboot into Ubuntu.
>
> If you upgraded to Windows 8 and are using BIOS firmware, Wubi does
>   work, but do not enable hybrid-sleep on Windows 8